# Trying to understand some SAS syntax

Tags: sas

I work with SAS EG at work and am pretty familiar with it, but am just now trying to pick up the basics of programming in base SAS using SAS university.

Can someone please take a look at the below code and tell me what the @1 and @7 mean when I'm declaring these columns... I think it has something to do with the length of numbers allowed?

Thanks in advance!

```
DATA MYDATA1;
   INPUT **@1** COL1 4.2  **@7** COL2 3.1;
   ADD_RESULT = COL1 + COL2;
   DATALINES;
   11.21 5.3
   3.11 11
   ;
PROC PRINT DATA= MYDATA1;
RUN;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `@1` and `@7` as used in your code indicate the column position at which SAS should expect to find the input data. So col1 data should be found in data column position 1 onwards and col2 should be found in data column position 7 onwards.

You might need to realign some of your data to be consistent with the expected @column input positions.

Answer (score 1):

The `@` in an `INPUT` statement is used to move the column pointer.  So `@1` moves to the first column.

Note that your example datalines are all indented by three spaces, so your program will not run. If you place the DATALINES (or CARDS) statement starting in column one then the editor will automatically move to column one when you insert lines to begin typing your data.  The program will also then be clearer to the reader if the DATALINES statement is in column one.

Note that your first value is too long for the INFORMAT that you are using the in the INPUT statement.  You used a width of 4 characters, but the value has 5 characters, counting the decimal point.

Also you will normally only include a decimal part on a **informat specification** when you know that the raw data has purposely **NOT** supplied an actual period character to indicate the boundary between the ones and tenths place.  So if your raw data value was `1121` then reading it with `4.2` would result in the number `11.21`.

```
DATA MYDATA1;
   INPUT @1 COL1 5.  @7 COL2 3.;
   ADD_RESULT = COL1 + COL2;
DATALINES;
11.21 5.3
3.11  11
;

PROC PRINT DATA= MYDATA1;
RUN;
```